# How to grep for line-separated strings containing a comma in a text file?

Tags: grep

I have a textfile with the following strings with a comma in them:

```
John,Smith
Jane,Doe
```

How can I grep * using this textfile?  I've tried to use `grep -xFf textfile *` but I don't get any results even if there are files that contain these strings.

a sample datafile within * contains this line:
`1231920383939,'unix:///run/John,Smith','{}'`

input: `grep -xFf textfile *`

output:  (blank)

Comment: The data files contain text in this format:
1539198827392,'John,Smith','{}'

if I use `grep -xFf samplefile *` I can't get that line for some reason

Comment: I think I can use `grep -wFf textfile *` instead, running some tests now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to boil down to the erroneous inclusion of the `-x` option to `grep`, which requires that the matched text be the only text on the line. Remove the `x` flag and you'll get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  For some reason I couldn't get any output at first even when not using the `-x` option.  The grep works now without the `-x` flag